# Change Div font size

Tags: css, html

I would like to change the font size of several rss links found inside a div

```
<div class="rss">
    <%
                    DocumentBuilderFactory dbf = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
                    DocumentBuilder db = dbf.newDocumentBuilder();
                    Document d = db.parse("http://www.engadget.com/rss.xml");
                    d.getDocumentElement().normalize();
                    NodeList items = d.getElementsByTagName("item");
                    for(int y = 0 ; y< 5 ; y++)
                    {
                    String title = "", description = "" , link = "";
                    NodeList subitems = (items.item(y)).getChildNodes();
                    for(int x = 0 ; x< subitems.getLength() ; x++)
                    {
                    if(subitems.item(x).getNodeType() == Element.ELEMENT_NODE)
                    {
                    if(subitems.item(x).getNodeName().equals("title")&& title.isEmpty())
                    {
                    title = subitems.item(x).getTextContent();
                    } else
                    if(subitems.item(x).getNodeName().equalsIgnoreCase("link") && link.isEmpty())
                    {
                    link = subitems.item(x).getTextContent();
                    } else
                    if(subitems.item(x).getNodeName().equals("description") && description.isEmpty())
                    {
                    description = subitems.item(x).getTextContent();
                    }
                    }
                    if(!description.isEmpty()&&!link.isEmpty()&&!title.isEmpty())
                    {
                    %>

                    <a href="<%=link%>"><%=title%></a>
                    <br/>
                    <%
                    break;
                    }
                    }
                    }
                    %>
</div>
```

from css file I have tried this:

```
    .rss
    {
       font-size: x-small;
    }
```

but then I noticed that this css was probably overwriting it:

```
    body, div, dl, dt, dd, ul, ol, li, h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, pre, form, p, blockquote, th, td { margin: 0; padding: 0; font-size: 14px; direction: ltr; }

p { font-family: "Helvetica Neue", "Helvetica", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; font-weight: normal; font-size: 14px; line-height: 1.6; margin-bottom: 17px; }
p.lead { font-size: 17.5px; line-height: 1.6; margin-bottom: 17px; }
```

so then I also tried to add:

```
  div.rss{
    font-size: xx-small;
    }
```

still not working.

what can I do to make those links smaller?

Comment: if i change the "global" dive font size it will change but then all the text in other divs will appear smaller and I only want links to appear smaller

Comment: I also tried a script in the head of the page and it works but I will change all other divs because the page where the links are located are the footer.

Comment: If these are links you are trying to make smaller, did you try `div.rss a {...` in your CSS?

Comment: Can you post an example on jsFiddle.net?

Comment: please find updated the links (rss)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To better define your css class you should try the following.

```
.rss a { }
```

Of-course that is assuming you do not have it wrapped in any other tags like the `li` tag. It would be more helpful if you could post the actual html as well.

You probably have a class that is overriding the `font-size` for your links so changing it to the above css should help override the css with your new settings.

Comment: You can also add another class to your link itself. For instance: `<a class="rsslink" href="<%=link%>"><%=title%></a>` and then use this for your css `.rss a.rsslink {}` that would even better define your css rule and you can even try adding `!important` to it as well.

Comment: You can add that like this: `.rss a.rsslink {font-size: 11px !important;}` thats assuming you added the class `rsslink` otherwise change it to `.rss a`

Comment: Also, if you are still having trouble you can use inline css instead of external css. Inline css always overrules external css.

Comment: inline worked. cheers. I was doing a div inline before that change my whole css but I did inline rsslink and it worked :) Thanks